# How to add an icon in Activity bar of Visual Studio Code that will trigger a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to add an icon in Activity bar of Visual Studio Code that will trigger a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Or executing a command from Command Palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only extensions can add an icon in the activity bar (officially called a "views container"). They cannot trigger a command, though. See the official documentation here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/extending-workbench
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_custom-activity-bar-views

However, maybe these extensions might fit your needs, they allow creation of custom commands in the status bar or the editor menu bar:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seunlanlege.action-buttons
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerrygoyal.shortcut-menu-bar